# Commandlink action does not work after an ajax call JSF-2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

The commandlink link2 does not have work after an ajax call is made to render a panel group panel1. This was working when the whole page was relaoded instead of ajax call to display the modal.

Main.xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel1">
<ui:fragment rendered="#{downloadTo.showModal}">
    <ui:include src="modal.xhtml" />
</ui:fragment>  
</h:panelGroup>

<h:form>
  <h:commandLink id="link" value="download" action="#{backing.openModal()}">
    <f:ajax render="_panel1"/>
 </h:commandLink>       
</h:form>
```

modal.xhtml contains

```
 <h:form>
   <h:commandLink id="link2" value="download" action="#{backing.downloadData()}"/>
 </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the backing bean holding the condition for the `rendered` attribute is `@ViewScoped`. Otherwise the condition will be reinitialized to default on the ajax request. You also need to change the `<f:ajax>` render to explicitly include the client ID of any other `<h:form>` which is to be ajax-updated, otherwise it will lose its view state.

E.g. in `modal.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="downloadForm">
  <h:commandLink id="link2" value="download" action="#{backing.downloadData()}"/>
</h:form>
```

with this change in `main.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink id="link" value="download" action="#{backing.openModal()}">
    <f:ajax render="_panel1 _downloadForm" />
 </h:commandLink>       
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm)

Answer (score 0):

what i see is, that you are rendering `_panel1` not `panel1`. this should work:

```
<h:commandLink id="link" value="download" action="#{backing.openModal()}">
    <f:ajax render="panel1"/>
 </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: This won't work. It's placed in a different naming container. The naming container separator character defaults to `:`, but is configureable. Often `_` or `-` is been used to comply CSS spec. The OP is apparently using `_` as naming container separator character.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Adding the client id to the render attribute solved the issue.

Comment: Even more, if `_panel1` was invalid, OP would have received a `FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id '_panel1'`.

Comment: @BalusC: By adding the client ID in render attribute, there is a ajax call error for the second call in IE and Chrome. And also we reset the form values before rendering the page. But the rendered page still displays the old values.